# How to select all rows with 2 unique columns with Sequelize.JS?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a table named `grade` with 4 columns: `student_id`, `subject_id`, `grade`, and `date`.

| student_id | subject_id | grade | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jenny | math | 90 | 2021-12-08 |
| Susan | math | 60 | 2021-12-08 |
| Jenny | math | 80 | 2021-12-07 |
| Susan | math | 50 | 2021-12-07 |
| Jenny | science | 80 | 2021-12-08 |
| Susan | science | 90 | 2021-12-08 |
| Jenny | science | 76 | 2021-12-06 |
| Susan | science | 85 | 2021-12-06 |

I would like to select all rows with only the last grade of each student for each subject. Basically, I want to select all rows with unique `student_id`, `subject_id`, like this:

| student_id | subject_id | grade | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jenny | math | 90 | 2021-12-08 |
| Susan | math | 60 | 2021-12-08 |
| Jenny | science | 80 | 2021-12-08 |
| Susan | science | 90 | 2021-12-08 |

Here is what I have tried:

```js
await Grade.findAll({
    attributes: ['student_id', 'subject_id', 'grade', 'date'],
    raw: true,
    group: ['student_id', 'subject_id']
})
```

However, I get the following error:

```
SequelizeDatabaseError: column "grade.grade" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Comment: I don't know how to write in the Sequelize.JS but in postgres you need to use window function over (student_id and subject_id ) order by date DESC and

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close. You are grouping by `student_id` and `subject_id` and you just need `MAX('date')`.

```
await Grade.findAll({
    attributes: ['student_id', 'subject_id', 'grade', [Sequelize.fn('max', Sequelize.col('date')), 'date']],
    raw: true,
    group: ['student_id', 'subject_id']
})
```

An array in attributes can perform function and alias to a given name `[function, alias]`.

For example:

```
[Sequelize.fn('max', Sequelize.col('date')), 'new_name']]
```

this syntax in attributes create SQL as

```
MAX(`date`) as `new_name`
```

========================================================

Update:

The above query doesn't work in Postgres.

ref: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/194352

To achieve the same query in Postgres, 1 alternative solution is to use `DISTINCT ON`.

```
await Grade.findAll({
    attributes: [Sequelize.literal('DISTINCT ON ("student_id", "subject_id") *'),
    'id', 'student_id', 'subject_id', 'date', 'grade'],
    order: ['student_id', 'subject_id', ['date', 'DESC']]
})
```

More about `DISTINCT ON` query, please check https://zaiste.net/posts/postgresql-distinct-on/

This article also touches upon the use of window function as @sia mentioned.

Some interesting benchmark of `DISTINCT ON` and `ROW_NUMBER`
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34715134/2956135

Comment: Thanks @Emma! I tried to add `id` to the attributes and got the following error: `SequelizeDatabaseError: column "grade.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you add your current `findAll` function in your original question?  Please keep the original code.

Comment: Your answer didn't work and I got the following error: `SequelizeDatabaseError: column "grade.grade" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`. It only worked when I removed the `grade` attribute.

Comment: my bad. I was testing on `sqlite` but this SQL is not allowed in postgres. I will update.

Comment: Thanks @Emma for your very helpful answer!